# AADSTS90094 Unable to grant permission to apps publisher is 'Microsoft Accounts'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have an app whose publisher is 'Microsoft Accounts', we want to grant the graph api to this application, but there is no way to grant the permission in the portal, now user get error 'xxx needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it. AADSTS90094: The grant requires admin permission.', how to resolve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your organization is using the app reigster from [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com)(Azure AD V2.0 endpoint).

If I understand correctly, the Azure portal doesn't support grant admin consent. We need to perform the request like below:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
```

More detail please refer the link below:

[Scopes, permissions, and consent in the Azure Active Directory v2.0 endpoint -
 Using the admin consent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint)

Comment: Thanks this helps, however the app is listed in enterprise applications not in app registrations, and I cannot found it in the v2 app registration portal either, so I cannot find the redirecturl, but it is listed as a required parameter in the admin consent endpoint, any way I can figure out values to pass in?

Comment: If the app was not register by your organization, you can get the redirect URL when you try to login this app. Check the authorization request and it should have that parameter. Also you may contact the support of that app to provide the UI to preform granting the admin consent. The **enterprise applications** section is different with **app registrations** which only list the service principal which **app registration** list the apps.

Comment: Refer [Application and service principal objects in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects)